# Securing a PHP webservice for application access only

Tags: php, .net, web-services, security

First of all, a better question would be is this possible? My gut instinct is that it isn't entirely, but there may be some clever ways. Even if they just act as a deterrent, make it slightly harder for some one to hack, or even make it easier for me to detect suspicious activity.

Basically, I'm building a web service using PHP for my C#.NET program to connect to. Among other things, one of the most important purpose the web service serves is verifying license data. The program sends the licence key entered by the user to be checked, and if it is valid the web service will return the Name of the person who purchased the licence key so that the program knows to activate itself.

I am fully aware that there is no perfect anti-piracy scheme and that is my software *will* be cracked if people want it bad enough. However, I do not believe that there isn't anything I can do to make it very hard for people to crack my software.

I do have an SSL certificate so the program will be communicating with the web service using HTTPS, however that's the only security I have at the moment. I have thought about

- Using long and obscure names so that the functions are hard to guess
- Using MD5 to disguise the functions
- Adding a username and password
- Checking the User-Agent
- etc.

However, I have read that there are applications available to simply extract strings from programs, which would render those measures completely ineffective. Still, I don't know how technical users have to be to use those applications. Is it still worth adding some of these measures to stop casual piracy? Which measures are the better ones and what will be the most effective?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute your C# application with a certificate bundled and sign your requests with the certificate. The server can then verify if the request was signed by your application and reject any other request.

Edit: Whoops, I only now understood that you want to secure you application even when in the hands of a malicious user. This, I don't think is possible. A hacker can decompile, scan the memory, read and decode files, etc and your certificate will be available in there if you distribute it with the application. An alternative would be to distribute an external security token (hardware device or flash storage) which will need to be plugged-in to the client computer. The token holds the certificate, keys or cyphers used to sign/encrypt your requests and it therefore doesn't stay with the application.

Your server-side SSL certificate will only guarantee that the communication channel is secure and the server is not lying about his identity. It doesn't guarantee anything about the client connecting. To also be sure that the client is identified, you need to use a form of client certificate that your server recognises.

Comment: Could you add any links or anything on how to do that please? I'm quite new to 'web programing'. Also, how easy would it be for someone to extract the certificate and use it to sign their own requests?

Comment: Sure, there's plenty of material to read on the subject. I recommend starting with wikipedia's description on [Public-Key Criptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). Once you understand the subject you can move on and use a ready-made library for C# and one for PHP (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I think I now understand PKI a bit better. However, as you say in your edit, I don't think this method would be suitable as it would be super easy for a hacker to get hold of the keys, and the alternative that you suggest isn't really practicable either. How do companies like Microsoft get around this?